# Cannot print/output anything with std::cout

Tags: c++

I have code here: http://ideone.com/Q6kzBQ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
    std::string message;
    while (true){
        int col;
        std::cin >> col;
        if (col == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        else if (col > 0){
            std::string letter;
            std::cin >> letter;
            //std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
            int letter_length = letter.size();
            int row = letter_length / col;

            message = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < col; i++){
                int current_row = 0;

                while (current_row != row){
                    if ((current_row % 2)){
                        message += letter[i + current_row * col];
                        std::cout<<"current:" << message<<std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        message += letter[current_row * (col + 1) - i - 1];
                        std::cout<<"current:" << message<<std::endl;
                    }
                    current_row++;
                    //std::cout<<"current:" << message<<std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << message <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I put in some inputs, but it does not output anything, not even the "yep" at the beginning. Is there something I did not do correctly? cout is from  so I think I've included everything I needed. But somehow nothing shows up on the stdout area of ideone.com. I have not tried this code on any other compiler. Suggestions? Sometimes, it does output 3 blank lines (if I take out all the other frivolous outputs, for my input there should be 2 lines with strings + a new line so 3 lines would be correct).

Input I used:

> 5
>  toioynnkpheleaigshareconhtomesnlewx
>  3
>   ttyohhieneesiaabss
>  0

Comment: I really doubt there's any problem with cout. What happens if you remove ALL the code besides `std::cout<< "yep";`

Comment: As tested, this has nothing to do with cout. Something weird happens in your code. You could try removing and re-adding everything line by line to find the problematic one.

Comment: @LeibnizMan Hi, does my answer help solve your problem. In case you still have issues, please comment or edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
message += letter[current_row * (col + 1) - i - 1];
```

You may undershoot the array index which leads to undefined behavior and hence you may or may not get any output.

**Solution**

Revise your calculations to ensure the index generated is inside the bound of `letter.size()`

I guess what you want is actually:

```
message += letter[(current_row + 1) * col - i - 1];
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To reach to the character beyond last in current row you need `(current_row + 1) * col` and not `current_row * (col + 1)`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/IXquAr)

**One possible explanation of no output**

When you access out of bound characters, you end printing some garbled characters in stream. When this stream is tried to print on a web page, the web engine rejects to print anything.

Comment: Thanks! I looked through my code and finally got it!

Answer (score 1):

Run your code manually.

1. The first run will have these result:

current_row = 0

current_row%2 = 0

i = 0

--> Your code will enter the "else" condition:

message += letter[0*(5+1)-0-1] // letter[-1]  violate!

2. This index may overflow array:

letter[i + current_row * col];  //i+current_row*5